Virtual environment Windows
Our task is linkage / build of C# projects. Build of projects are done under dedicated user on a single Windows host. Building of different branches requires uneven set of dependencies/packages, while Nuget /dotnet package manager uses user's home folder as default location. This results in conflicts during a build and improper dependencies issues. The host is Windows Server 2019 on top of VMWare VM. For best of my understanding, this version doesn't support Windows containers. And as long as application isn't .Net core compatible - Linux container isn't the option. Create an additional VM host would be an option, but currently this is off-topic. We're looking for lightweight solution - the one that doesn't imply tempering drastically current build environment.
Is there a way in Windows to create isolated development environments - similar to Python's virtual environments or chroot and Nix in Linux?

Based on the documentation from Microsoft, MS Windows Server 2019 should be able to support containers, in this case they use "Docker Desktop" application. You could try installing Docker Desktop on the Windows 2019 server? If it works out, you will have to apply for a yearly license.
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/setup/install/windows-install/
Compared to a Virtual Machine, Docker Desktop is lightweight. Mileage will vary based on the CPU/Memory you can allocate to the Windows 2019 server VM.

Thanks for pointing out In general, Windows container sounds a plausible option.
Yet it doesn't apply to the case due internal restrictions. I indeed looked for   straightforward  solution to embed into existent pipeline - sort of CLI extension.  that being said, I tend to mark the answer as accepted.
